# Nunjucks include is unexpectedly inserting text into DOM

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I am using Nunjucks with Express and node.js. I am confused why Nunjucks causes text to be inserted into the DOM that shouldn't be present.

Example:

templates/test.html:

```
<div></div>
```

test.html:

```
{% include "templates/test.html" %}
<div>
    This is a test...
</div>
```

The source generated is as expected:

```
<div></div>
<div>
    This is a test...
</div>
```

However it doesn't render as I would expect. When inspecting the DOM:

```
""
<div></div>
<div>
    This is a test...
</div>
```

As expected if I remove the "" from the DOM using developer tools it renders as I would expect.

If anyone explain this and suggest a way to prevent it happening I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I answered your question, but made it Community Wiki so I won't get reputation from it (AFAIK - I've never made community wikis before). This way you can [accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), signalling the community your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The OP solved it himself/herself:**

Typically I have already worked out the answer ;)

Nunjucks whitespace control using '-':

```
{%- include "templates/test.html" -%}
```

This strips whitespace before and after.

(I couldn't answer my own question due to being a new SO user)

Comment: @TreeMan360 nunjucks issue [{% spaceless %} tag #207](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/207) may be also helpful for this kind of problems